# Delayed Job worker fails when trying to send Devise mails in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app deployed in a VPS. This app uses the `Delayed_Job` gem to manage asynchronous tasks, specifically email delivery. When executing `RAILS_ENV=production rake jobs:workoff` to send all pending confirmation emails, it returns the following message:

```
Devise::Async::Backend::DelayedJob#perform failed with NameError: uninitialized constant Devise::Mailer - 0 failed attempts
```

I've followed all steps as seen in https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Send-devise-emails-in-background-(Resque,-Sidekiq-and-Delayed::Job).

Comment: please read through this issue. does it help? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1751

Comment: I guess I must add `require 'devise/mailer'`, but where?

Comment: if you run rake with a `--trace` option, you can see where the error is getting raised. somewhere in the callstack should be a good point to add this require statement.

Comment: @Sergio in user.rb